# ios cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called however numberOfRowsInSection gets called and returns a number

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

My application is using JASidePanels libraries and I had set them using storyboard. The center view is a UITableView and the left panel is a view in which I call a method (by pressing a button)

```
- (IBAction)reloadAllFilters:(UIButton *)sender{

MasterViewController *masterController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"centerViewController"];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfFilterIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// another code

masterController.filterIdsToDisplay = arrayOfFilterIds;
[masterController.tableView reloadData];

[self.sidePanelController toggleLeftPanel:self];
```

}

The thing is, that when the app starts, the number of rows returned by number, but after I call this method, the number of rows is 30 but I cant see nothing.

I think that the problem is that I am instantiating a new masterController and therefor I cant get the actual table view to be displayed? Or am I wrong? Can you please help me?

Comment: where is the data in "arrayOfFilterIds" Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. You create a new master controller every time you call the method

From UIStoryboard reference:

> This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it.

You need to get the existing one.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can get to that view and not instatiate it? I dont have any segues set between those two, because if I had and went through that segue, I could not animate to the center view, am I right ?

Comment: Just create a outlet property in your header file and connect it in storyboard. Then you can use the property to access the masterController

Comment: That looks easy :) but where should I create it ? And ti which controller should I add it .. I have just made a custom segue and then in prepareForSegue I am setting the property of the masterViewController. Is that gonna do it?

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MasterViewController *masterController; you put that in header file(mycontroller.h) of the controller in which you have reloadAllFilters: method. Then you will see a circle next to line numbers(if you have enabled). Click and drag from that circle to MasterController in storyboard.

Comment: Since I havent used Interfacebuilder and storyboard for a long time, It can be changed or I remember wrong. But give a try :)

Comment: I have tried it but the problem is, when I drag from circle of the property masterController, it doesnt want itself to be attached to the MasterController. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the delegate and datasource to your tableview 
like this ...

```
  tableView.delegate = masterController;
  tableView.dataSource = masterController;
```